# What design pattern is PEAR DB_DataObject implementing?

Tags: php, database, design-patterns, pear

[DB_DataObject](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.db-dataobject.php) does not appear to be ActiveRecord because you do not necessarily store business logic in the "table" classes. It seems more like Table Data Gateway or Row Data Gateway, but I really cannot tell. What I need is good ORM layer that we can use with DataMapper and a DomainModel. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow [this link](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.db-dataobject.intro-purpose.php) to read what DB_DO is. In a nutshell, it doesn't implement a specific pattern, it just aims to provide a common interface. The idea is to not rebuild the same basic code in each project.

As for an ORM, I'd recommend [Doctrine](http://phpdoctrine.org/). It implements ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're looking for is something like [IBatis](http://ibatis.apache.org/) for PHP. Sadly, this doesn't yet exist. I've actually written some custom DataMapper stuff based on PDO for the current application I'm working on to achieve a persistence ignorant domain layer. It's definitely more work to develop and maintain though, so I would suggest if at all possible, go with an existing data layer implementation like Doctrine for most of your needs.